# My program does not stop running after finishing child process

Tags: c, fork, exec

I am now learning about folk, exec etc and I have this piece of code:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int status;
    childpid=fork();
    if (childpid== -1){
        perror("Failed to fork\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid==0) {
        printf("I am in child process with id = %lu\n", (long)getpid());
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        perror("exec failure ");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("I am in parent process with id = %lu\n", (long)getpid());
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

The child process works fine but after that for some reason the program continues running without doing anything. It never prints "I am in child process with id = ...." or "I am in parent process with id =... ". It's like it never goes to parent process. Do you have any ideas why? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are creating a _zombie_ process. This is because the parent process is not _waiting_ for the child to complete. The parent process will terminate [relatively] quickly. Thus, the child loses its parent and becomes a _zombie_. A zombie will be reparented by the kernel as a child of process 1 (e.g. `systemd` or `initd`). To fix, add: `wait(NULL);` after the final `printf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Therefore do I need to always put wait(NULL) in these types of situations?

Comment: Can you fix the spelling in your question so it can be useful to other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comment ...

You are creating a *zombie* process. This is because the parent process is not waiting for the child to complete.

The parent process will terminate [relatively] quickly. Thus, the child loses its parent and becomes a zombie. A zombie will be reparented by the kernel as a child of process 1 (e.g. `systemd` or `initd`).

To fix, add: `wait(NULL);` after the final `printf`

---

**UPDATE:**

> Therefore do I need to always put wait(NULL) in these types of situations?

The TL;DR is ... Yes!

This is what you normally want to do for most programs.

One of the few times you *would* want to create a zombie is (e.g.) if you're a server program (e.g. `inetd`).

Servers *want* to run "detached". That is, as a child of the *init* process (e.g. `systemd`, `initd`, etc.). There is one and only one *init* process on the system.

All other processes are children of *init*, even if indirectly. For example, your program's process hierarchy was something like:

```
init -> window_manager -> xterm -> bash -> your_program
```

Anyway, most server programs these days are fired up by `systemd` directly. It examines some config files and starts things based on these config options. So, now, most server programs don't have to do anything special.

But, *if* you were testing a server of your own, invoked it from the command line, and wanted it to run [detached] in the background, you might do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int opt_d;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    pid_t childpid;
    int status;

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // detach into background
    if (opt_d) {
        childpid = fork();

        if (childpid == -1) {
            perror("Failed to detach\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // exit the parent -- child is now detached [and a zombie] and a child
        // of the init process
        if (childpid != 0)
            exit(0);
    }

    childpid = fork();

    if (childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0) {
        printf("I am in child process with id = %lu\n", (long) getpid());
        execvp(*argv, argv);
        perror("exec failure ");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("I am in parent process with id = %lu\n", (long) getpid());
    wait(&status);

    return 0;
}
```